# ns3 execute function during simulation at regular time interval

Tags: intervals, ns-3

How can I execute a function every 20us for example?

I aim to log the busy/free state on a CSMA channel using `ns3::CsmaChannel::IsBusy` (is that the best way to do it?) I have to call it at regular time interval to log each returned value and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`simulator:: schedule function`

to schedule function on a regular time interval

`Simulator:: Schedule (Seconds(20.0), &function name, parameter1, parameter 2)`

This is the syntax for scheduling an event for every 20 seconds